# Filter as count on SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-aggregation

Helo!

How I make the following syntax of postgresql in SQL server without create subquery

PGSQL:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS "QUANTIDADE TOTAL",
    COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE SEXO = 'Masculino') AS "MASCULINO"
FROM FUNCIONARIOS;
```

I tried but got an error:
Message 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4

Incorrect syntax next to 'WHERE' keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
SELECT COUNT(x) as [Quantudate Total],
SUM (CASE WHEN SEXO = 'Masculino' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS MASCULINO
FROM FUNCIONARIOS

For better performance always better to use one specific field in the aggregate function than using a *, eg use COUNT(id) than COUNT(*)

Comment: Very thank you #Shah and #Isolated! With your help , I tried this and work very well, follow final code:

SELECT TOP 1
 COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
 SUM((CASE WHEN SEX = 'W' THEN 1 
     WHEN SEX <> 'W' THEN 0
  END)) AS 'MASCULINO'
  FROM [DATA_SCIENCE].[dbo].[LOSS_JOBS_COVID]

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation would work...

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS "QUANTIDADE TOTAL",
    SUM(case when SEXO = 'Masculino' then 1 end) AS "MASCULINO"
FROM FUNCIONARIOS;
```

Comment: I think you'll need `ELSE 0` inside `SUM` (behavior is different with `COUNT`).

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker Works with or without `ELSE`. It's a preference if you would rather return null vs 0 if no data matches. Based on the OP's query, I doubt that Masculino would not be found.

Comment: I guess "works" depends if you actually want a count or if NULL is a reasonably expected substitution for 0.